# JodaTime::toDate returns different dates

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I faced a little trouble. I wrote some code and tests. I had to check operating with dates into some objects, then I created a few test data like this:

```
task.setPlannedTime(
          DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
          .parseDateTime("4/27/2018 08:00:00")
          .toDate());
```

And I have a few more tasks like that. These are stubbed data which would be returned when some method will be called, never mind, the point is somewhere around.

The tested code is some sorting about a list of these tasks. And then I check in tests that I sorted these data correctly. I use the same statement as before to create date to compare with. (I use TestNG). And test method looks like the following:

```
testSmth() {
    setupMockData(getStubbedTaskList()); // get stubbed data and then just some mocking
    handler.doSomething();
    List<Task> tasks = getCapturedTasks();
    //and here I want to check if the first element has correct date
    assertEquals(
              tasks.get(0).getPlanendDate(), 
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                     .parseDateTime("4/27/2018 08:00:00")
                     .toDate()
    );
}
```

> `getStubbedData` is a method that returns a list of stubbed tasks with
>   different dates like in the first code listing.

The point is that it works. I run tests locally using maven and IDEA test runner. Everything is fine. But once it appears on CI/CD (we use Jenkins) I got a failed build.

The reason is strange. When I create test data like int the first code listing on CI/CD the date is always `Fri Apr 27 01:00:00`. But, in the assertion statement date has been created correctly `Fri Apr 27 08:00:00`. And I got an assertion error because the expected date was  `Fri Apr 27 08:00:00`, but actual is `Fri Apr 27 01:00:00`.

I mean, both dates, for assertion and stub are created the same way in the same class in the same test method. But for the stubbed data all dates are parsing into something strange. How is it possible? It doesn't look like a typical issue with time zone or something like that.

Every voice is appreciated. Would be really thankful for any thoughts.
Thanks.

P.S.:
The reason why I don't think that because of time zone it's that every date is always the same: `Fri Apr 27 01:00:00` when I create for `08:00:00`, the same when I create for `13:00:00` and so on. 
P.S.S: Java 7...

Comment: There’s something going on behind the scenes. Please create a self-contained [mcve] that reproduces the problem, as the code that you’ve posted now is not sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you try another date, are you still getting Fri Apr 27 01:00:00 or 01:00 on that other date or something else? Agree with @ErwinBolwidt that we don’t have the information needed to spot the problem, though.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  Unfortunately, I can't do that quickly because this is a big company project with the code I can't just share. Anyway, thanks for responding. I solved the issue by avoiding JodaTime. This thing works unpredictable a bit with different versions of JDK. I have 1.7_80, CI/CD operates with 1.7_51. And colleagues with 1.7_51 get the same errors locally. And I just removed all jodatime code here.